# How do I pass props to cards in React Semantic UI Card.Group?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic UI's `Card.Group` component to show a bunch of cards. The data comes from an external JSON, formatted, and passed down to the group's `items` prop.

I'd like to pass props to the cards in the group (i.e. make them `raised` or set `size="mini"`), how can I do that? Or do I have to use `.map()` on the items JSON, and specify a `Card` component with the props?

Update: code (as much as it is useful here):

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card, Container} from 'semantic-ui-react';

//assume this JSON comes from an API
const items = [
  {
    "header": "header1",
    "meta": "meta1",
    "description": "description1",
    "image": "image1.png"
  },
  {
    "header": "header2",
    "meta": "meta2",
    "description": "description2",
    "image": "image2.png"
  }
];

export default () => (
  <Container>
     <Card.Group stackable items={items} />
  </Container>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened an issue on the React Semantic UI Github repo, and got the following answer:

> It's a general behavior of shorthands and works across all components
>  So, yes, you can use .map() and specify matching props.

```
const items = [
  {
    header: 'Project Report - June', // these props are passed to Card
    meta: 'ROI: 27%', 
    color: 'red',
    raised: true,
  },
  {
    header: { content: 'Project Report - June', textAlign: 'right' }, // these to Card.Header in Card
  },
]
```

I hope this will help anyone who needs to pass props to child components in React Semantic UI.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing any code, but usually, with JSON objects you will have to use a `.map()` to parse through the array.

Comment: I've added a minimal code sample. If you're unfamiliar with `Card.Group`, as you can see, you do not need to reiterate through the JSON for the cards to get drawn - `Group` does it for you.